# Getting errors when calling UIGetScreenImage() in background

Tags: iphone

when my application enter background , Appear as follows error information：

```
012-10-18 14:38:05.964 SoundRecorder[693:14603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Cannot call UICreateScreenImage() while app
is in the background.'
```

this is my code:

```
- (void) getImage
{
    CGImageRef screen = UIGetScreenImage();
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:screen];
    CGImageRelease(screen);
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, nil, nil);
    NSLog(@"1");
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.5];
}

- (void) applicationDidEnterBackground: (UIApplication*) application
{
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{  
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];  
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;  
    }];  
    dispatch_async(
        dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{  
        while(1){
            [self getImage];
            if(breakpoints != 1)
                break;
        }
        NSLog(@"run at backgroud!");
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];  
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;  
     }); 
}
```

Comment: What’s inside `[self getImage]`?

Comment: CGImageRef UIGetScreenImage(void);
-(void)getIamge{
    CGImageRef screen = UIGetScreenImage();
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:screen];
    CGImageRelease(screen);
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, nil, nil);
    NSLog(@"1");
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.5];
}

Comment: It’s best to add the code into the question, it’s hard to read in the comments. I’ve edited the question and added the missing code for you, you can delete the comment now.

Answer (score 2):

Well, according to the error message it’s not possible to call `UIGetScreenImage()` and related functions when your app is in the background. It makes sense, it would be a huge security hole.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use dispatch_async, you have to call this function within a background thread instead.

Calling dispatch_async within the main/UI thread could cause the function to be called many times(as async returns right away) even before the last one is done and overwhelm the queue.

I can confirm that it works if you call it inside a different thread other then the UI.